Unable To Clone LI Element Inside Template
I have:


const tmpl = document.getElementById("tmpl");
const cloned = tmpl.content.cloneNode(true); // doesn't work
<template id="tmpl">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
</template>



tmpl.content doesn't work if the first element is a li element.
Problem:
I cannot clone the template child like ie:tmpl.content.cloneNode(true)
Expectation:
const cloned = tmpl.content.cloneNode(true)

returns
<li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>

Why is this happening?

Your code works as provided: https://jsfiddle.net/vuw9qpd0/  Perhaps this is specific to your browser - which browser are you using?   The MDN reference for permitted parents (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#technical_summary) does not include template - so it could be being "fixed" by the browser - check via inspect element equivalent.  You would be able to get around this by adding a ul in your template, then, after cloning, select the li.

@fdomn-m You are right. I am so dumb. I used Visual Studio. In my actual code, all of my template tag is templates, with the s. Visual Studio doesn't highlight validation error on the tag, but on the <li>. How do i close this question?

Add an answer with how you fixed it, include code, accept your answer.  It's a valid question.

The problem is that the content of a <template> element is a DocumentFragment. When you clone it, you get another DocumentFragment.
To get the li element, you need to access the children of the cloned DocumentFragment.
Here is a minimal example:


const tmpl = document.getElementById("tmpl");

const clonedFragment = tmpl.content.cloneNode(true);
console.log('clonedFragment:', clonedFragment.constructor.name);

// Select the element to clone
const cloned = clonedFragment.firstElementChild;
console.log('cloned:', cloned.constructor.name);

// Add the cloned element to the document
document.body.appendChild(cloned);
<template id="tmpl">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
</template>




It's not necessary to select the <li> before appending. You can append the entire DocumentFragment with document.body.append(clonedFragment).

@EmielZuurbier True, it is just that the OP did not say how they want to use the <li> element. So the only logical assumption for me was that they want to manipulate the element further, for which they need to access the element itself.
